# Flutter: fit GridView inside Container

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a dynamic GridView that needs to be placed inside a Container. I don't want to have scroll, when this happens, the grid should be resized to fit completely inside the container.

This is the widget:

```
Row(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            flex: 2,
            child: leftColumn(),
          ),
          Expanded(
            flex: 1,
            child: rightColumn(),
          ),
        ],
```

---

```
  Widget leftColumn() {
    return GridView.count(
          primary: false,
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
          crossAxisSpacing: 5,
          mainAxisSpacing: 5,
          crossAxisCount: totalResultLength + horizontalGap,
          children: <Widget>[
            for (int i = 0; i < totalRows * totalColumns; i++) numberBox(i),
          ],
        );
}
```

[image]

Comment: what does "resized to fit completely inside the container"?  Do you want it to get proportionally smaller in both width and height?  Just shorter?  And if reduced, should the font size get smaller?  Or just get more squished up into the box?

Comment: I had the same app made using HTML/JS/CSS and basically what I did here was to do the same calculation to paint the cards and after that take the full size of it and make it smaller with some css property.
This would be the same. I cannot paint less cards so all of them should be reduces along with the font size (this is already dynamic based on the card size). It's basically making it smaller proportionally

Comment: Consider FittedBox with BoxFit.contain or .fitWidth.  It will scale up and down as needed.

Comment: I'll have a look, thanks

Comment: Feel free also to add an answer to accept it

Comment: I added extra info. Didn't mention the GridView was inside a Row

Comment: This doesn't seem to work well with the GridView